# control package not found

Tags: errors, packages

I'd like to control the LaTeX `Error File fictitiuspack.sty not found`, for example. This is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fictitiuspack}
\begin{document}
     Hello world
\end{document}
```

Of course, the `fictitiuspack.sty` doesn't exist. If I compile the MWE, I obtain

```
! LaTeX Error: File `fictitiuspack.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: X
```

It's possible to control this error before this error happens? For example, If I could control, I could write:

```
ifnonexist{\usepackage{goodpackage}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
\IfFileExists{packageA.sty}{\usepackage{packageA}}{\usepackage{packageB}}
```

Comment: Yes, something like it

Comment: Then use it :).   You can add some messages to the branches for the log file ("Cannot find A, so switching to B") etc.

Comment: Of course, I did not know \IfFileExits command, I'm sorry. I up vote.

Comment: @jpayansomet You can accept answers by clicking on the tick mark besides an answer of your choice. :)